# I have a desktop running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit that is connected to the internet but will not open a webpage in any browser. Any ideas

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a desktop running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit that is connected to the internet but will not open a webpage in any browser. I can ping websites and even remote in to the pc via the internet but when I try to browse the internet or update software it appears not to be connected. I have researched several places and have try numerous things but my problem still persists. Any help on the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you researched?

Comment: In my research I have taken the following steps to solve the issue:
- reset winsock
- uninstall and reinstall network driver
- Malwarebytes Scan - program will not connect to update server
- Hitman Pro Kickstart Scan - Pc connected to Internet to run the program but after the program ran and a reboot the PC still will not let me browse the web.

Comment: Can you ping? Can you access the router admin?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access a webpage by entering its IP address into the browser? Try 198.252.206.140 (superuser.com). If this works, you are either not connected to a DNS Server or it is down. Check the router settings for DNS servers. If there is no entry, put in 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) and try again.